# After following up and not be contacted, is it okay to make contact?

Tags: job-search, follow-up

I was reading [this link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/is-it-normal-for-a-company-not-to-contact-you-after-a-lengthy-interview-to-let-y?rq=1), but my situation  is a little different because I never had an interview.

I submitted my application to a job posting twelve days ago, and after not hearing back from them, I decided to followup with an e-mail stating that I'm interested in the job, and looking forward to hearing from them. I re-submitted my resume/cover letter in the followup e-mail. I still have not heard anything from them.

I **assumed** that I wasn't a good fit for the job, and so they passed on my application. The issue is, the job posting states that if you don't have any experience, they will train you. I have experience, some of which exceeds that of the requirements. My **assumption** is, given the simplicity of the job (data entry), a lot of people have applied, and they simply haven't reviewed my application yet. The job posting is still open, but I'm unsure of what to do, do I wait? Is it okay to make contact and ask about my application?

I highlighted the word **assumption** because, no one has made contact, so I can only guess as to what is going on, which I know is dangerous, and making the wrong move could get my application tossed (again, I assume).

Comment: It sounds like you have done all that is reasonable. Any more follow ups and you risk annoying whoever is dealing with this (and if the issue _is_ that they have way too many applicants, the last thing you want to do is give them any additional reason to reject you).

Comment: @delinear not true.  Followups show you want the position.  Now, if you follow up every day, then yes,  you become a pest.

Comment: _A_ follow up is fine, likewise if the company has subsequently been in contact and you think of something new to ask, then it's fine to get back in touch. However at this point OP has already contacted them _twice_ with no feedback. The likelihood is, that means they have been rejected, but there is a _slim_ chance their CV just hasn't been looked at yet. I don't think bombarding the company with requests until they respond is necessarily the best way to create a good first impression (I know, having been on the hiring side of the equation, it would put me off instantly), but of course YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a follow up once per week isn't excessive, once every other week is fine, but it should be brief, maybe a line or two.

> Hi, I just wanted to check in with you to let you know I'm still interested in this position, and still available.  Thanks.

or something like that.  Use language like "checking in" and "following up".  Be courteous, not demanding, and you should be fine.

Do not send your application again, and keep following up until you either get a response, or see the job ad disappear.

I've known more than one candidate get hired simply because they were persistent.

Comment: +1, while I like this approach, I hesitate to try it because all the advice I've seen suggests to do one followup and move on, but I'll try it and see what happens. Why shouldn't I send my application again?

Comment: @EmilyScott If they're not going to hire you, you won't do any damage, if you're in the running, it will show you want the job.  Just don't do more than once a week, once every two weeks is acceptable as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, why shouldn't i send my application again? Is it bad practice?

Comment: @EmilyScott yes, resending your application is making the assumption that they've lost it, now **THAT** might annoy them.  What I usually do when I send an application is include in the email or cover letter, something like.  **Thank you for your time, as a followup, I'll [call/email] next Thursday**

Answer (score 2):

You have already sent a follow up email so there is nothing additional for you to do.  The reasons they may not have contacted you could be that they don't contact applicants who aren't considered for a position or that they have many applicants and have not had a chance to evaluate your application.  There are many other possible reasons for why they have not contacted you as well.

Regardless, you should not be "putting all your eggs in one basket".  If you are looking for new work you should be applying to several companies simultaneously.  It should not be such a big deal if any one company hasn't reached out to you as you should have several potential companies lined up.  If this is the only company that you have applied to, I would recommend applying to others.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a country tag on this question.

I come from Portugal, before moving out of Portugal I sent 200 applications, by either dropping my CV in places, filling applications, going to job agencies...

The overwhelming response of 0 emails sent by them flooded by email account...

I moved to the UK and have received a response around 70-90% of the times a response when I have not been sucessfull. Entry level jobs have a lower response rate as well.

Just understand that for them, you are 1 in X that has sent the application.

The fact you mention they offer training is often a blanked statement used in recruitment, if they had received 2 applications they may hire someone who needs training but if they receive 1000 applications they will only contact the ones who don't require training as this is the most cost-efficient hire for the company they are hiring for.

Just carry on searching, change your CV about and try new things with it and see what works. For example, if you want to do an entry job in Helpdesk, or administration or Data entry, then prepare a "specific" enough CV for each one of those and send them through when you are applying.